# Run code if JMP instruction fails in NASM?

Tags: nasm, bootloader, osdev

I'm writing a bootloader and was thinking about how to jump to the kernel. I saw that people use `jmp 0x8000` (or whatever address the kernel is at) in order to load it. but if the JMP fails for whatever reason (like there being nothing at the kernel, or the kernel being 64 bit when we are in 32 bit mode,) how could I make NASM run some different code instead? for example, It would attempt a JMP to the kernel address but in the case that whatever is there can't/won't run, it could print a message stating that the kernel could not be loaded?

Comment: A `jmp 0x8000` instruction never "fails". You just jump there. If there's nothing there, then you execute garbage, or you take a fault, depending on how much of the MMU you've set up.

Comment: What fails is not the jump (it just set the instruction pointer register). What really could fail is the instruction or whaterver is at the jump target.

Comment: then how can i check whether or not there is something at the point that i'm about to `jmp` to? or if possible, check that the point that i'm about to `jmp` to contains executable code?

Comment: @TheTetrisDude you can always read what's at that location like this and then act on that information:

`mov ecx, 0x8000; mov dword eax, [ecx]`

Preferably you would instead use a debugger like GDB and look at the memory in runtime. There's probably other parts of your code that you can error handle then the `jmp`  as the commenters before me mentioned.